# Can sub-domain be on a different hosting?

Tags: routing

Our company website is developed in WordPress, but the services that we offer to customers are developed in .Net.

I was wondering if I can host our company website CompanyName.com onto a linux based hosting like BlueHost, and host our service Portal.CompanyName.com on a windows hosting like Microsoft Azure.

Comment: Would love to know how this networking question is "off-topic" on "networking stackoverflow"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  You can.  You are simply describing different A records.  You can have as many A records as you need.

You can even host the domain and the subdomain on different DNS hosts.  This is referred to as DNS Delegation.

However, DNS is off topic on this Stack Exchange.  You'll get a much more thorough answer on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course. That's part of DNS.

You can set different records for each sub-domain, including A, MX, etc..

You would do the following:

```
sub1.domain.com A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
sub2.domain.com A yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```